# How to create a Spatial Reference object from Calculate UTM Zone output?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

I have a function that extracts the well known text representation of a UTM zone:

```
def find_utm_zone(shp):
    """
    -Generates a UTM zone for the feature
    """
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
    gdb = arcpy.env.scratchGDB
    fc = os.path.join(gdb, "temp_fc")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(shp, fc)
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "utmzone", field_type = "TEXT", field_length = 1000)

    # Execute CalculateUTMZone
    arcpy.CalculateUTMZone_cartography(fc, "utmzone")

    prj = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "utmzone")][0]
    return prj
```

The output looks like the following (i.e. the same as a .prj file):

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 UTM Zone 18L (Calculated)",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-75.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

When I try to create a Spatial Reference object from the output I get a generic `RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.` error:

```
shp = r'C:\path\to\myshapefile.shp'
sr = find_utm_zone(shp)
print arcpy.SpatialReference(sr)
```

What is the preferred method of creating a [Spatial Reference object](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/spatialreference.htm) from the [Calculate UTM Zone](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/calculate-utm-zone.htm) output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the options for [`arcpy.SpatialReference`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/spatialreference.htm#S2_GUID-ABFF41D0-C10F-42DD-971C-07B1FB918002) is a `prj` file, so write your output to a temp `prj` and read that in.  Something like:

```
shp = r'C:\path\to\myshapefile.shp'
sr = find_utm_zone(shp)

myprj = r"myTempPrj.prj"

with open(myprj, "w") as prjFile:
    prjFile.write(sr)

print arcpy.SpatialReference(myprj)
```

Which for me returns:

```
<geoprocessing spatial reference object object at 0x000000000D2E29B0>
```

Then just delete your temporary `prj` file when it's finished.

Comment: Thanks, this works, although I needed to replace `print(sr, file=prjFile)` with `prjFile.write(sr)`.